# Why does \setbeamercolor{math text}{…} cause an extra newline after equation at end of block?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing, equations, color

The code below creates additional vertical space after the equation in the block, if the equation is the last thing in the block. Otherwise, if there is some additional text after the equation (e.g., if you uncomment the line below the equation), there is no unwanted vertical space.

The unwanted space disappears if the line `\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}` is commented out. I know that the beamer manual states that the `math text` color option is somewhat fragile. But I was wondering how exactly that space is caused and whether this specific issue can be easily fixed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}{}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}
% additional text
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here are images of the problem (compiled with MacTeX-2020, last updated via TeX Live Utility a few weeks ago). First with the `\setbeamercolor` line and afterwards without it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide an image of this problem. I see no difference when compiling with up to date TeXLive 2021

Comment: I just added corresponding images to the post. I'm using TeXLive-2020 (under MacOS, so actually MacTeX) and updates from CTAN from a few weeks ago.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue but I don't have the newest TL2021. However, my gut tells me that the color `\special` is messing with the vertical list; that can happen...

Comment: I get the same (I misunderstood something in the MWE).